# django==1.4 support for html5

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a small blog app I have built using Django 1.4 and recently, I have been learning "bits and pieces" of html5 and css3. I am about the start transitioning my site to html5/css3 and I was wondering if Django widgets support html5(?)

My blog is nothing special - a few forms, a few tables etc.. For example when I do,

```
{{form_as_p}}
```

I was wondering if django would generate the required html5 markup(?) I read the docs, and it says the admin pages support html5, but I could not find any docs for regular apps.

If html5 is not supported by Django, what is the best way going about achieving this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django's form output is XHTML. Django does not snip with support for the new HTML5 input types such as number, email, url, etc but it is not difficult to add them. See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16630 or https://github.com/rhec/django-html5 That being said I don't know any place where Django generates markup that is invalid for HTML5.

Comment: thanks for this answer. It would be interesting to know why in django docs they say all admin pages support HTML5. I wonder what it really means.

Comment: The only change I'm aware of is that the DOCTYPE of the admin default templates was changed to HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

"If html5 is not supported by Django, what is the best way going about achieving this?"

I have been trying a monkeypatch approach with very encouraging results so far, the big bonus for me is that there is no need to change your existing code, or for modifying third party apps, or Django admin. This keeps things very clean and central and there is no need for hairy and repetitive `admin.site.register(...)`/`admin.site.register(...)`.

https://github.com/danielsokolowski/django-html5monkeypatch